# Issues about insalling Cinelerra video editor?

Tags: 12.04, installation, video, ppa, editor

In order to install Cinerella I typed in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

But after last command typed, my computer gives me an error below?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cinelerra is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'cinelerra' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do (I'm using ubuntu 12.04 Lts)

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [website](http://cinelerra.org/getting_cinelerra.php#ubuntu) the command that you need to install is

```
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```